# 2 player 2 decks card game

Tags: identify-this-game

This game is called Touch in Egypt (my country) but I can't find it online.  Can anyone help me with the real name of the game?  Also I would love to hear any competitive strategy I can use to win!

**Setup**:

- Two players
- Two shuffled decks of cards
- Players create 8 columns that can be completed like K-Q-J-10-etc but in different colors.
- Aces are drawn out so the both players can complete the Aces' columns according to their suite and order.

**Rules**:
Each player has two piles to draw from, one is faced up that other player can put his cards on if they are the same suite and according to their order like if you have 3 of hearts, I can put my 4 of hearts on it.

**Game play:**
Players take turns...

**TOUCH:**
if any player made unnecessary move, like arranging the columns when he/she had the chance to complete an Ace column, the other player can say "TOUCH" ending the first's turn.

**Win condition:** you need to finish both of your piles.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Russian Bank](https://www.pagat.com/patience/crapette.html), which seems to have a wide variety of different names (including Touch) in different countries. (I knew it as Cravat when I grew up playing it in the UK).